# Setting an HTML5 page so it fits all devices without scrolling it

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have an HTML5 application for mobile device. For now, I have handled all the problems of width-height with a simple scroll, if needed. Now I have one page with a lot of content with absolute places. I want it all be seen as one screen without scrolling it.
On [Samsung Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy) it's looking fine, but on [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) not all stuff get into to the page and is not being seen.

I tried to change it with viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

But it didn't solve the problem.

How can I take one big div with content and put it in like in a box, so it will for sure send just in different resolutions?

Comment: Just a heads up – this is surprisingly hard and most likely will require quite a lot of manual tweaking to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one `div` in the `body` and set `width` and `height` to `100%` all other content can be places inside...this is a one way of doing it.

Is that what you have asked?

Small example:

```
<body>
  <div id="content" style="width:100%;height:100%">
      //play with the content
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried it, but different results in different devices,in Iphone I see things cut from the end, in the end of the page what not happening in Samsung.

Comment: I did it,placed it all into div with the above settings and removed the meta tag,its not working. I wonder... there's no one solution for this kind of issue?